# Simple signature validation (with no request-derived credentials) failed

Tags: spring, spring-saml

I have an existing spring webapp which uses SAML to let users login via a third party site. Users login on the third party site and use SAML to single-sign-on into my application. The third party site recently had their certificate expire and they sent me a new .crt file to import into my java keystore. I used the following commands to update my java keystore:

```
keytool -delete -alias thirdPartyCertificate -keystore myKeystore.jks
keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias thirdPartyCertificate -file 2017-third-party-certificate.crt -keystore myKeystore.jks
```

Both commands completed successfully (and I can run a -list on the keystore and see that the new certificate is present and not expired). However, after I restarted my java webserver, the single sign on did not work. It threw the following two warnings and then failed to login the user:

```
WARN  org.opensaml.common.binding.security.BaseSAMLSimpleSignatureSecurityPolicyRule - Simple signature validation (with no request-derived credentials) failed
WARN  org.opensaml.common.binding.security.BaseSAMLSimpleSignatureSecurityPolicyRule - Validation of request simple signature failed for context issuer: <certificate_url_omitted>
```

What would cause the certificate validation to fail? I don't think that their certificate is bad because several other webapp maintainers were able to successfully use the new certificate. Is there some step that I missed in installing the new certificate?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to set the *signingKey* property to alias of the certificate you imported in the ExtendedMetadata of your IDP. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-saml/docs/1.0.x-SNAPSHOT/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-key-management (8.2.1)